# Create function that takes in IP or DNS name and pings it

Tags: python, ping

Having trouble writing a python script that will ping an IP or DNS name from the command line. The function needs to return the IP and the time to ping it as a list.  If the IP or DNS cannot be pinged, the function will return the IP and 'Not Found' in a list.  This script also needs a main function that reads in a single IP or DNS name on the command line, calls the function to ping it, and then displays the result as:

IP, TimeToPing (ms)
10.1.2.3, 10

This is what I have so far:

```
import ipaddress
import subprocess
from pythonping import ping

    #Main routine
    def main():
        try:
            address = sys.argv([1])
            pingthis = ping(address)
            header = "IP, TimeToPing (ms)"
    
    
    # Run main() if script called directly
    if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()
```

So far, I'm getting an TabError for indentation for the line: header = "IP, TimeToPing (ms)". Is this line suppose to be pushed back?

Comment: Do you have an editor which is mixing tabs and spaces? That is the most common cause of this error.

Comment: I'm using nano as an editor

Comment: The indentation you show here is incorrect. Please double check to show what you actually have. Also, as Nick ODell says, be sure you use only tabs or only spaces. Don't mix them.

Comment: If you download and install VS Code or PyCharm, they both have options to show your whitespace. This can help you determine where you have tabs and where you have spaces.

Comment: I fixed the error, but now I'm getting an error for the if __name__ == "__main__": saying there is an unexpected indent. There is no indent for that line. Also, I have used all spaces for indentation for the script

Comment: everything after your imports is unexpectedly indented though

Comment: It isn't like this on my machine for it, this just the way it was formatted after Ctrl + K

Comment: Well this is what you gave us and you're reporting indentation issues. Python is super strict about indentation. It isn't an optional part of the language like C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few syntax errors in your code. I would definitely recommend reading/watching some videos on correct python syntax and you'll be good in no time!

```py
import ipaddress
import subprocess
from pythonping import ping

# unindent everything below like this

#Main routine
def main():
    try:
        address = sys.argv([1])
        pingthis = ping(address)
        header = "IP, TimeToPing (ms)"
    except SomeSpecificException:
        # every try statement must have an except, otherwise, whats the point?
        # code that only runs when the exception is caught

# Run main() if script called directly
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # your line below was 4 spaces over-indented
    main()
```

Comment: _every try statement must have an except_ A `finally` block syntactically suffices, too. But yes, `except` and/or `finally`are needed to complete the compound statement.

Comment: Worth noting that the `except` block can't be empty - if you don't want to do anything when the `except` is triggered, then you need to put `pass` inside there so it isn't empty.